# Solving a system of a system of equations, numerically.

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

I have a system of 4 systems of equations.

$$\begin{align*}
  C - 0 &= 1.02 \\
  C - F &= 0.45 \\
  C - N &= 0.24 \\
  C - I &= -0.21 \\
\end{align*}$$

$$\begin{align*}
  F - 0 &= 0.59 \\
  F - C &= -0.45 \\
  F - N &= -0.20 \\
  F - I &= -0.68 \\
\end{align*}$$

and so on.

Obviously, I can just say that $C = 1.02, F = 0.59$. But then $C - F = 0.43$, not $0.45$, as the second line indicates. Is there a way to solve for the best approximation for $C, F, N, I$, or am I better off not wasting my time and just going with $C = 1.02$, etc.?

I've tried setting up a matrix equation for each system, and solving the normal equations symbolically in Matlab, but that didn't work out too well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can arrange all the equations in a whole system in the form $Ax=b$ with $x=(C,F,N,I)$ and solve by [least-squares method](https://it.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/least-squares-fitting.html)

$$A^TA\hat x=A^Tb \implies \hat x =(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$$

Comment: Just to expand the answer here: The usual way to do this is via QR-decomposition of $A$. This has better numerical properties compared to solving the $A^TA$-system and is preferable for large ill-conditioned systems of equations.

Comment: @Laray Thanks for your interesting comment! Bye